# Something in my html code is giving me a Parse Error using Grunt htmlmin

Tags: parsing, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-htmlmin

I am getting a parse error when trying to use grunt htmlmin this happens when I run my grunt build when I run with a --force I get that 2 of the three pages return an error.  I think there is something wrong with my HTML potentially where do I need to look?

```
Running "htmlmin:dist" (htmlmin) task
Warning: dist/index.html
Error: Parse Error: <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="https://formspree.io/xaywqrrw" method="POST" / role="form" data-toggle="validator">
                             <div class="form-group row">
                                 <label for="firstname" class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">First
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that slash "/" in the middle.

**method="POST" -------> / <------ role="form" data-toggle="validator">**

It's supposed to be at the end of the tag or at the beginning only (for closing tags).